# Closed sets in a given topology

Tags: general-topology

I came across a topology on $ \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z $ whose basis is defined as follows:

$ B(m,n) = \lbrace (m,n) \rbrace $ if both m and n are odd

$ B(m,n) = \lbrace (m+a, n) | a = -1, 0 ,1 \rbrace $ when m is even and n is odd

$ B(m,n) = \lbrace (m, n+a) | a = -1, 0 ,1 \rbrace $ when m is odd and n is even

$ B(m,n) = \lbrace (m+a, n+b) | a,b = -1, 0 ,1 \rbrace $ when both m and n are even

I was trying to determine the smallest possible closed sets given a point, as the problem requires me to. I showed that when both the coordinates are even, its just the singleton set which is closed.

But in the remaining cases, I think it has to be the entire set itself. However I am lacking a rigorous proof to establish my claim. Can anyone guide me??

Comment: I think your second conclusion is wrong - the smallest closed set containing a point is the intersection of all closed sets containing that point. Can there really be no non-trivial closed set that contains $(1,0)$ or $(1,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider the point $\langle 0,1\rangle$, say. A point $p\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is in the closure of $\{\langle0,1\rangle\}$ if and only if every open nbhd of $p$ contains $\langle 0,1\rangle$. This is the case if $p$ is $\langle 0,2\rangle$ or $\langle 0,0\rangle$, but that’s it. To see this, let $p=\langle m,n\rangle$. If $m<-1$ or $m>1$, $p\notin B(m,n)$, and similarly if $n<0$ or $n>2$. Thus, we need only consider the nine points in the set $\{-1,0,1\}\times\{0,1,2\}$, and in all cases except the two already noted, $p\notin B(m,n)$.

This argument easily generalizes to show that the closure of $\{\langle 2k,2\ell+1\rangle\}$ is the three-point set $\{\langle 2k,2\ell\rangle,\langle 2k,2\ell+1\rangle,\langle 2k,2\ell+2\rangle\}$ for any integers $k$ and $\ell$. That is, if $p$ is an even-odd point, so to speak, the only points that can’t be separated from it are the two adjacent to it vertically.

Now try to analyze the remaining cases in the same general fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I should have just picked up on a specific point to work on than wandering around arbitrarily.

Comment: @Vishesh: You’re welcome. Sometimes it really does help to look at a few concrete examples, especially when, as here, you can actually draw useful pictures.